# Retrieve property by reference

Tags: c#, properties, pass-by-reference

I am new in C#. I am from Java world. So I am confused with the following code:

```
    class A
    {
        private PointF point;

        public A(PointF point)
        {
            this.point = point;
        }

        public PointF Position
        {
            get { return point; }
        }
    }
```

I want to change X-coordinate of the position property, so I perform:

```
        A a = new A(new PointF(1,2));
        PointF p = a.Position;
        p.X = 100;
        Console.WriteLine(a.Position.X); // <--- I have 1 here!
```

I wonder why the output is NOT **100**? As I have understand I have received reference on private field with Position property. Am I right?

Can I change property without adding set-property and propagating **Position** with new **PointF** object?

Comment: No, you can not. Because PointF is structure and it is value type.

Comment: Yes you can. Can you paste the code of your PointF, I think the setter on PointF.X isn't doing what it's supposed to do. -- EDIT: oh I didn't realize PointF was a struct and not a class... So your `p` variable is a brand new struct copied from a.Position. If you want it to be a reference, you have to either encapsulate PointF in a class or define a new type as a class. Or you can use the Point class.

Comment: You sure about that??!!! I tested abd it's working. Could you also add the PointF class in your sample. EDIT: lol i didn't saw the struc neither

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No; `PointF` is a `struct`, so it has copy semantics and **is not an object**; as soon as you've obtained it - it is a separate and isolated copy (unless you're using something like `ref`/`out`, which is ... more subtle). The struct is actually copied multiple times in your example.

By the way, a consequence of this is that it is actually a very bad idea to have mutable structs - so in most cases you should avoid the scenario where you can say:

```
p.X = 100;
```

since that causes more confusion than it helps. In particular the following is completely invalid:

```
a.Position.X = 100; // won't even compile
```

(here the compile is spotting that you are changing a copy of the struct that only exists during the mutation itself, which means your change goes *nowhere*, and is almost certainly a bug)

Answer (score 2):

`PointF` is a Struct. In .Net Framework structs are **valueTypes**. So your example will always print out 1.

It does not matter that you are using it within a class. Every time you assign a value to a variable of a value type, *the value* will be copied.

Comment: You mean it will always print out 1, not 100.

Answer (score 2):

The `PointF` is value type with all consequences.
If you want change the only "X" property of `PointF` value in property, you need copy the value into variable, change the "X" property and the set the changed value of property.

```
var cls = new A();
var point = cls.Point;
point.X = 15;
cls.Point = point;
```

Answer (score 2):

In C# there are two types of variables - value types and reference types. When assigning value types they are copied - for reference types, the *reference* gets copied.

`Point` is a value type (a `struct`) and on assignment gets *copied*. So:

```
PointF p = a.Position;
```

`p` is a *copy* of `a.Position`, completely separate from it. So:

```
p.X = 100;
```

Modifies the value of `X` on `p`, leaving `a.Position.X` untouched.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use saved words out(function) and ref(when send to function) to pass parameters by reference

Comment: Passing a struct by-reference does not let you *store* the reference; it will be dereferenced when assigned to anything.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you compiler doesn't give you a warning.
Whats happening here is that you are not returning a PointF reference, which presumably is a value type,  in fact you returning a copy. Then you modify that copies X property. Of course this cant work.

Comment: This is not an error (although it is inadvisable) because you could still do something interesting with the mutated local copy. The time it errors is when you try this directly on a property-get.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `p` and `a` are two distinct objects, so changing the former doesn't affect the latter.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you have the [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)

```
class A 
{ 
    public PointF Position {get;set;} 

    public A(PointF point) 
    { 
        this.Position = point; 
    } 
} 

A a = new A(new PointF(1,2));    
    a.Position.X = 100  
    Console.WriteLine(a.Position.X);
```

Comment: That won't even compile since `PointF` is a `struct`; you can't mutate a `struct` via a `get`